# PHP Export Indexed Array into CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have a following indexed array

```
$export_data = array (
  [0] => 1,
  [1] => 2,
  [2] => 3,
  [3] => 4,
  [4] => 5,
  [8] => 9,
  [9] => 10,
);
```

I know how to export it to csv using fputcsv. However what my issue is that I need to export the data into correct column i.e. value in $export_data[8] needs to be exported in column 9 not column 6.

How can this be done please ?

Comment: simple: build your array properly in the first place. if you want a value in "column 9", then you put it into the spot of the array that REPRESENTS column 9, which is index 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, boss.

```
$export_data = array_replace(array_map(function($v){return null;}, range(0, max(array_keys($export_data)))), $export_data);
```

---

Tested 100,000 iterations and results are in seconds:

```
Version     Run1  Run2  Run3
PHP 5.6.20  .58   .55   .50
PHP 7.0.5   .18   .21   .21
```

---

Now for the explanation so I don't get flogged with downvotes or get accused of witchcraft.

```
$export_data = array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 4,
    4 => 5,
    8 => 9,
    9 => 10,
);

$export_data = 
    array_replace( // replace the elements of the 10-item array with your original array and the filled-in blanks are going to be null. I did not use array_merge() because it would append $export_data onto our dynamic range() array rather than replacing elements as needed.
        array_map( // loop the 10-item array and apply the declared function per element. This function ends up returning the 10-item array with all keys intact but the values will be null
            function($v){return null; /* return ''; // if you prefer and empty string instead of null*/}, // set each value of the 10-item array to null
            range( // create an 10-item array with indexes and values of 0-9
                0,
                max(array_keys($export_data)) // get the highest key of your array which is 9
            )
        ),
        $export_data // your original array with gaps
    );

var_dump($export_data);
print_r($export_data);
```

Comment: Thank you really appreciate for your time and response. All the other answers were correct however this does exactly what I needed in one line of code. Also great explanation thanks again.

Comment: @user4676307 I'm glad you like it. I was initially considering a similar approach to [Jimmmy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5545687/jimmmy) but wanted to show you the power of all the various PHP functions :-). Good luck with your project!

Comment: Witchcraft! :-) i like yours solution, it will be sure quicker than mine on longer arrays (which csv mostly are). +1

Comment: @Jimmmy believe it or not but your solution is almost twice as fast as mine, lol. With some minor optimization, it can go even faster.

Answer (score 2):

if i understand correctly, you want to put free columns between data, so the keys match column number.

```
$arr = array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 4,
    4 => 5,
    8 => 9,
    9 => 10,
);

$csvArray = array();
$maxKey = max(array_keys($arr));
for($i = 0; $i <= $maxKey; $i++){
    if(array_key_exists($i, $arr)){
        $csvArray[$i] = $arr[$i];
    } else {
        $csvArray[$i] = null;
    }
}
print_r($csvArray);
```

demo here: [live demo](https://3v4l.org/LtZhT)

to describe it, just cycle through array and check wether key is set, if is, assing its value to the next array, if is not, assign null

---

Optimized:

```
$csvArray = array();
$maxKey = max(array_keys($arr));
// ++$i is microscopically faster when going for the long haul; such as 10,000,000 iterations
// Try it for yourself:
// $start = microtime(true);
// for($i=0; $i<10000000; $i++){}
// echo (microtime(true) - $start).' seconds';
for($i = 0; $i <= $maxKey; ++$i){
    // we can use isset() because it returns false if the value is null anyways. It is much faster than array_key_exists()
    $csvArray[$i] = (isset($arr[$i]) ? $arr[$i] : null);
}
```

Comment: Hi, i did not know about ++$i Vs. $i++, but i am against isset() in this case, because null can be common value of the array (and key exists). In my example it does not make difference, but in other uses it can..

Comment: `++$i` is one of those things that doesn't help as much as it used to especially with PHP 5 and 7 but it is still around. One of the main areas where it can mess with you is doing stuff like `echo 'This iteration #'.++$i;` vs `echo 'This iteration #'.$i++;`. As for the `isset()`, it can certainly cause a headache for anyone unaware of the gotchas.

Answer (score -1):

I would just fill the array completely with empty values for the empty columns:

```
$export_data = array (
  [0] => 1,
  [1] => 2,
  [2] => 3,
  [3] => 4,
  [4] => 5,
  [5] => '',
  [6] => '',
  [7] => '',
  [8] => 9,
  [9] => 10,
);
```

Without the indexes (because they are automatic in any case):

```
$export_data = array (
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  '',
  '',
  '',
  9,
  10,
);
```